# 1 row from DataSet A to many from DataSetB

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-grouping

I'm trying to create a report that display's a document that is in the DB across multiple tables. I have the querys and datasets set up fine, I'm just having issues grouping it right on the report itself.

To make it clear

I have one Row from Dataset A that needs to be displayed and under it, each Row from dataset B.

like

```
        Dataset A fields 
        (basically a "for each")
         Dataset B fields

         Just keep repeating "for each"
```

How do I go about this?

Comment: It doesn't sound like you have the datasets set up fine. Your question is a teeny bit vague, but I think you should be returning only one dataset to get the output you require. Join the datasets in the query rather than in SSRS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you do is return the relevant field(s) from Dataset A on every row with the fields from Dataset B and then group on the Dataset A field. For example:

```
SELECT DatasetA.Id, DatasetB.Code, DatasetB_Description, DatasetB.Value
FROM DatasetA
INNER JOIN DatasetB ON DatasetA.Id = DatasetB.DatasetA_Id
```

On your tablix, create a group that changes on `Id` and put the DatasetB fields in the Detail row of the tablix. Now each time DatasetA.Id changes, it will trigger a new group header and display all the DatasetB rows that relate to that DatasetA Id under it.